# Regex to extract subdomain from URL?

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of domain names coming in like this:

http://subdomain.example.com (example.com is always example.com, but the subdomain varies).

I need "subdomain".

Could some kind person who had the patience to learn regex help me out?

Comment: Yes, you can have string.string.domain.gtld

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
/(http:\/\/)?(([^.]+)\.)?domain\.com/
```

Then $3 (or \3) will contain "subdomain" if one was supplied.

If you want to have the subdomain in the first group, and your
regex engine supports non-capturing groups (shy groups), use
this as suggested by palindrom:

```
/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:([^.]+)\.)?domain\.com/
```

Comment: True. He didn't mention language/library so I wanted to make the regex as portable as possible - not sure if all implementations allow non-capturing groups.

Comment: What if you don't know what `domain` is?

Comment: @DallasClark In that case, I would recommend my answer below

Answer (score 52):

The problem with the above regex is: if you do not know what the protocol is, or what the domain suffix is, you will get some unexpected results. Here is a little regex accounts for those situations.  :D

```
/(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/i  //javascript
```

This should always return your subdomain (if present) in group 1.
Here it is in a Javascript example, but it should also work for any other engine that supports positive look-ahead assertions:

```
// EXAMPLE of use
var regex = /(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/i
  , whoKnowsWhatItCouldBe = [
                        "www.mydomain.com/whatever/my-site" //matches: www
                      , "mydomain.com"// does not match
                      , "http://mydomain.com" // does not match
                      , "https://mydomain.com"// does not match
                      , "banana.com/somethingelse" // does not match
                      , "https://banana.com/somethingelse.org" // does not match
                      , "http://what-ever.mydomain.mu" //matches: what-ever
                      , "dev-www.thisdomain.com/whatever" // matches: dev-www
                      , "hot-MamaSitas.SomE_doma-in.au.xxx"//matches: hot-MamaSitas
                  , "http://hot-MamaSitas.SomE_doma-in.au.xxx" // matches: hot-MamaSitas
                  , "пуст.пустыня.ru" //even non english chars! Woohoo! matches: пуст
                  , "пустыня.ru" //does not match
                  ];

// Run a loop and test it out.
for ( var i = 0, length = whoKnowsWhatItCouldBe.length; i < length; i++ ){
    var result = whoKnowsWhatItCouldBe[i].match(regex);
    if(result != null){
      // YAY! We have a match!
    } else {
      // Boo... No subdomain was found
    }
}
```

Comment: this is clearly the best answer because it accounts for protocol, none/multiple subdomains, and it is domain independent.

Comment: I would wonder the desired output of multiple subdomains... Would you want it to return `one.two` or just `one`? I suppose we could tweak the regex to pull all (.\.) groups prior to the domain... maybe later

Comment: Nice job, +1. `(file:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})` if you want to allow other prorocols

Comment: This worked in google analytics to filter by subdomain - had to drop the leading / and the trailing /i  `(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})`

Comment: @WebandFlow, The result `SomE_doma-in` is the subdomain of your example, is it not? I am unclear what you had expected, vs. what you got. I personally expect `SomE_doma-in` as the match...

Comment: @Pandem1c, sorry that wasn't the most explicit language. What I'm referring to is related to your examples, which contain `"hot-MamaSitas.SomE_doma-in.au.xxx"`. While in this case it works and catches `hot-MamaSitas`, if someone were to run just "SomE_doma-in.au.xxx" it would incorrectly identify the domain as a subdomain. It's definitely the correct regex for when a subdomain is guaranteed (just need a list of all domain extensions).

Comment: What are you expecting that the subdomain would be in your example `SomE_doma-in.au.xxx` ?I am still not following you... If the input is `SomE_doma-in.au.xxx`then the subdomain actually IS `SomE_doma-in`, right? Unless you are saying that containing a full-stop does not delineate the domain segments? From all i can tell,  the regex is not *incorrectly* identifying this... it captures the first group of alphanumeric chars before the first full-stop, which (for all intents and purposes) is the sub-domain.

Answer (score 6):

Purely the subdomain string (result is $1):

```
^http://([^.]+)\.domain\.com
```

Making `http://` optional (result is $2):

```
^(http://)?([^.]+)\.domain\.com
```

Making the `http://` and the subdomain optional (result is $3):

```
(http://)?(([^.]+)\.)?domain\.com
```

Answer (score 2):

It should just be

```
\Qhttp://\E(\w+)\.domain\.com
```

The sub domain will be the first group.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'http://subdomain.example.com';
my $subdomain = (split qr{/{2}|\.}, $s)[1];

print "'$subdomain'\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To math sub domains with dot character in it, I used this one

```
https?:\/\/?(?:([^*]+)\.)?domain\.com
```

to get all matching characters after protocol until domain.

https://sub.domain.com (sub)

https://sub.sub.domain.com (sub.sub)
...

Answer (score -1):

1st group of

```
http://(.*).example.com
```

Comment: Forgetting, of course, that `.*` will match an empty string and, more importantly, that the period stands for **any character**.