# Checking full domain from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I check either string is full domain or subdomain using regex.

like

```
abc.com | Full domain
xyz.abc.com | Subdomain
test.co.uk | Full domain
text.test.co.uk/ | Subdomain
```

Comment: why do you want to use regex?

Comment: There are domains like xxx.com.hk, which to regex will look the same as xyz.abc.uk. Don't use REGEX!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to extract subdomain from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189128/regex-to-extract-subdomain-from-url)

Comment: then what you suggest how to achveive it?

Answer (score 2):

Recursively do a DNS lookup, while removing one section from the left at a time

**subdomain**

```
xyz.abc.com //DNS check PASS
abc.com //DNS check PASS
```

**domain**

```
xxx.com.hk //DNS check PASS
com.hk //DNS check FAIL
```

If there no nameservers/DNS resolution fails for a different reason, the other way to confirm if it is a subdomain or not is to use IANA's TLD (Top-Level Domain) Registry [Here](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

**(USE CAUTIOUSLY)**

**There are several cases like `com.com`, `com.google.com`, and several other URLs using TLDs in their name.**

Comment: +1 for DNS Solution. You can't say without a lookup what is or isn't a second level domain.

Comment: What if valid domain name has no name servers?

Comment: If a DNS check fails, there is only one other way. To check it against all the names in the IANA registry. Updating the answer.

Comment: But some tld(s) are actually indirect, such as `us.com`, `de.com`, etc (see https://www.centralnic.com/names/domains), and IANA does not recognize them. Very well know such tlds are `co.uk`, `co.jp`, or `com.br`.

Comment: In my UPDATE, if you see a no-match just once, it is a domain. And if you see a no-match more than once, it is a sub-domain.

Comment: Domain name `com.domain.com` will have 2 matches by IANA and it is subdomain :(. How about `com.net.org.info.biz.jp.uk.co` ?

Comment: :D too many weird cases. In that case, all matches before the first no-match are counted as matches as well. I think you are better off sticking to the DNS resolution solution. When traversing from left to right.

Comment: There is com.com as well. This is too complicated and hence, worthless :) The DNS solution seems to be the best way for now.

Answer (score 0):

With Regex if not possible to check is a domain or subdomain. The most browser use for this problem the project of Mozilla - PublicSuffix. It is a maintained list of TLD.

You can use the following nuget package. (Install-Package Nager.PublicSuffix)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.PublicSuffix/

Example:

```
 var domainParser = new DomainParser();
 var data = await domainParser.LoadDataAsync();
 var tldRules = domainParser.ParseRules(data);
 domainParser.AddRules(tldRules);

 var domainName = domainParser.Get("sub.test.co.uk");
 //domainName.Domain = "test";
 //domainName.Hostname = "sub.test.co.uk";
 //domainName.RegistrableDomain = "test.co.uk";
 //domainName.SubDomain = "sub";
 //domainName.TLD = "co.uk";
```