# Regex Grouping (Retrieve subdomain)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match any url with a subdomain excluding "www".  I am trying to retrieve the subdomain after a match but can't seem to group it correctly.  My first group matches the whole url.  I would like to allow only lower case letters, numbers and "-" in the subdomain.  I need to retrieve just the subdomain if the pattern matches

```
^(((?!www)[a-z0-9\\-]*))+(\\.)+?example\\.com.*$
```

Comment: What language? Also, it's probably not the first group, but you just get a full string that successfully matched your pattern as "first group"

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?!www)([a-z0-9\-]+)\.example\.com.*$/
```

Group 0 will have the whole URL, and Group 1 will only contain subdomain

Comment: Thank you! Short and simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
/(http:\/\/)?(([^.]+)\.)?example\.com/
```

This should do the trick for you!

UPDATE

I also found another thread that responds to your question
[Regex to extract subdomain from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189128/regex-to-extract-subdomain-from-url)