# Need Javascript to change an ad tracker key based off sub domain name

Tags: javascript

I've currently got 4 different javascripts for ad tracking. They look something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var TrackerKey = 'keyabc123'; var url = 'http://website.com/jscode.js'; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.setAttribute('src', url); script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); document.body.appendChild(script);</script>
```

I want to combine all 4 and simply have the tracker key swap out based off the sub domain name they're on.

Thus far I've been able to work out that I would use the window.location.hostname to find what the domain is. And I would probably use a switch statement or if/else approach.

I'm not experienced enough though to know how to pass on the information of what the domain is as a variable to the switch statement, and then use that to update the tracker key variable.

I assume it might look something like the following...

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

var domain = window.location.hostname;

var TrackerKey;
switch (???) {
    case 0:
        sub.domain1.com = "keyabc123";
        break;
    case 1:
        sub.domain2.com = "keydef456";
        break;
    case 2:
        sub.domain3.com = "keyghi789";
        break;
    case 3:
        sub.domain4.com = "keyjkl012";
        break;
}

var url = 'http://website.com/jscode.js'; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.setAttribute('src', url); script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); document.body.appendChild(script);</script>
```

Am I remotely on the right path?

Apologies, this is my first stab at something beyond the very basics.

Comment: Your case should also reflect the hostname it matches, e.g., `case 'www.yahoo.com': ... break; case 'videos.yahoo.com': ... break;`

Comment: How do your subdomains look like in URL and their keys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close:

```
var domain = window.location.hostname;

var TrackerKey;
switch (domain) {
    case "sub.domain1.com":
        TrackerKey = "keyabc123";
        break;
    case "sub.domain2.com":
        TrackerKey = "keydef456";
        break;
    case "sub.domain3.com":
        TrackerKey = "keyghi789";
        break;
    case "sub.domain4.com":
        TrackerKey = "keyjkl012";
        break;
}
```

Also by convention in Javascript, variable and function names are camel case starting with a lowercase character, and Classes are camelCase starting with a capital character.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Silver bullet answer. I did a little document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
TrackerKey; to test and it's returning values as it should. Up to the server it goes for more testing, but I think it's gonna work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`var subdomain = window.location.hostname.match(/(http:\/\/)?(([^.]+)\.)?domain\.com/)[3]`

Change 'domain' above to your domain and then use

```
var TrackerKey;
switch(subdomain) { 
    case 'abc': //abc.domain.com
        TrackerKey = 'abc123';
        break;
}
```

And then do your usual script insert.

Regex ref: [Regex to extract subdomain from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189128/regex-to-extract-subdomain-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
function trackerKey(url){
  var d = url.replace(/^((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+).+$/i, '$4').toLowerCase();
  switch(d){
    case 'vancouver':
      return 'someKey1';
    case 'portland':
      return 'someKey2';
    case 'seattle':
      return 'someKey3';
    case 'losangeles':
      return 'someKey4';
    default:
      return 'someKey';
  }
}
console.log(trackerKey(location));
```

If you ran this code at `seattle.craigslist.org` you would see `someKey3` in your console. Likewise, `vancouver.craigslist.ca` would give you `someKey1`. Of course, you'd have to work for craigslist to run the above code. This is just an illustration. By the way, I would usually find it pointless to return a key or make a key based on known Client Side information. You should handle encryption Sever Side. Note that you don't have to type `window.` as it is implicit.